# How to import an .rcproject file into a Xcode project?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit, reality-composer

If I load an AR Game template it creates a file called Experience which is a Reality Composer file that you can reference in code. So you can see here:

```
let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()
```

[image]

Which is good... but how do I do this in my project? I created a Reality Composer file and added it to the project, but I cannot reference it?

[image]

[image]

And I cannot seem to find the additional link I need to add here to make it work? Do I have to call the file "Experience.rcproject", surely not?

Answer (score 0):

To load another Reality Composer scene (enumeration), you have to take four steps:

1. Rename `rook16.rcproject` to `Rook16.rcproject` in Xcode Navigator pane.
2. Consider Swift's ***enum*** naming convention. Write `Rook16.loadBox()`.
3. Select `Rook16` in Navigator, go to Inspector (file tab) and tick a Target Membership.
4. Restart your project in Xcode.

Here's the SwiftUI code:

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    let rook16 = try! Rook16.loadBox()
    arView.scene.anchors.append(rook16)
    return arView
}
```